# Two Different MVC sites sharing one database Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, iis, entity-framework-4

I have a database-driven site developed with MVC and Entity Framework code first. The database is rather large and contains all the data that I would need for an additional web application. What are the implications of setting up a new website with database first using the same existing database? What I am really trying to ask is whether it would be a bad idea to share a database between two web applications where both are querying and doing updates to the data. Will this slow down processing on the original site or possibly lock up data, etc.?  Both sites would be running on the same machine...

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sharing of the same data between both application is important i.e. you want the data to be shared between applications - than you have to use the same database. It'll slow down processing, but if it's the requirement, then you have to.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's going to be a judgment call on whether to share the data or recreate. I just wanted to make sure that it's possible to do.

Comment: Obviously it's possible. that's why u can access your `same data` of your fb account from your mobile application and also from web browser...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from having two applications accessing the database. They are built to have multiple connections with multiple people accessing them. So there aren't many risks involved. You probably won't even notice the speed difference.

The two biggest risks I can think of

- if both applications edit a record in the database, the one that submitted data last will win unless you put business logic in place to prevent that from happening
- if the database schema is updated, both applications need to be updated to reflect the new schema to let it access the new data, or edit the data successfully